# Implementing ECDF in R

Tags: r, statistics, probability

I'm trying to implement the R function `ecdf()`.

I'm considering two cases: one with `t` 1-dimensional, the other with `t` as a vector.

```
#First case
my.ecdf<-function(x,t) {
            indicator<-ifelse(x<=t,1,0)
            out<-sum(indicator)/length(x)
            out
    }


#Second case
my.ecdf<-function(x,t) {
    out<-length(t)
    for(i in 1:length(t)) {
            indicator<-ifelse(x<=t[i],1,0)
            out[i]<-sum(indicator)/length(t)
    }
    out
}
```

How can I check whether I'm doing the right thing with the R function `ecdf()` or not? This function take as argument just `x`, therefore I can't specify the value of `t`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just plot the results and see that it gives something very similar:

```
# slightly improved version of my.ecdf
my.ecdf<-function(x,t) {
  out<-numeric(length(t))
  for(i in 1:length(t)) {
    indicator <- as.numeric(x<=t[i])
    out[i] <- sum(indicator)/length(t)
  }
  out
}
# test 1
x <- rnorm(1000)
plot(ecdf(x))
lines(seq(-4, 4, length=1000), 
     my.ecdf(x, seq(-4, 4, length=1000)), 
     col='red')
# test 2
x <- rexp(1000)
plot(ecdf(x))
lines(seq(0, 8, length=1000), 
     my.ecdf(x, seq(0, 8, length=1000)), 
     col='red')
```

Answer (score 0):

A general tip - you can view the source code of any function by typing its name into the console without parentheses or arguments:

```
edcf
function (x) 
{
    x <- sort(x)
    n <- length(x)
    if (n < 1) 
        stop("'x' must have 1 or more non-missing values")
    vals <- unique(x)
    rval <- approxfun(vals, cumsum(tabulate(match(x, vals)))/n, 
        method = "constant", yleft = 0, yright = 1, f = 0, ties = "ordered")
    class(rval) <- c("ecdf", "stepfun", class(rval))
    assign("nobs", n, envir = environment(rval))
    attr(rval, "call") <- sys.call()
    rval
}
```

Comment: I knew about that, but I don't think it can help with my question.